# Javascript reset dropdownlist and checkbox

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have three form field, textbox, drop down list and check box. I would like to reset the drop down list to the first item and checkbox to uncheck if I click reset. I tried this code but it will only reset the textbox and not the drop down list. I would need some to reset the check box as well.

Note: The drop down list type was defined at model.

```
<input type="text" name="a" class="input-medium w1" data-bind="value: value" />

<label class="control-label" for="category" id="ProductType">Type:&nbsp; @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Type)</label>

<label class="control-label">Included Discontinued:@Html.CheckBox("searchDate")</label>


    var dropDown = document.getElementById("ProductType");
        dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;

    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var ii = 0; ii < elements.length; ii++) {
        if (elements[ii].type == "text") {
            elements[ii].value = "";
        }     
    }
```

Comment: `#ProductType` looks like a label, not a dropdown ?

Comment: It is a drop down list  [RequiredValidator(ErrorMessageCategory = "General", ErrorMessageId = "RequiredField")]
        [DropdownList("ProductType")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

For unchecking check boxes use

```
document.getElementById("ID").checked = false;
```

**For example**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  What color do you prefer?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue">Blue
</form>

<button onclick="check()">Check "Red"</button>
<button onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck "Red"</button>

<script>
function check() {
    document.getElementById("red").checked = true;
}
function uncheck() {
    document.getElementById("red").checked = false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_radio_checked2

For drop down list use

```
document.getElementById("orange").selected = "true";
```

**For example**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
Select your favorite fruit:
<select>
  <option id="apple">Apple</option>
  <option id="orange">Orange</option>
  <option id="pineapple" selected>Pineapple</option> // Pre-selected
  <option id="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
</form>

<p>Click the button to change the selected option in the dropdown list to "orange" instead of "pinapple".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("orange").selected = "true";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_selected2

Comment: I already have values in dropdownlist. I tried this function Reset() {
        document.getElementById("red").checked = false;

        document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex = 0;
    }

Comment: Second example shows the answer. You need to assign id to  <option> element which have default value and set it active (.selected=true;) on reset button click.